# Mohamed Salah plays for liverpool. To ask a question, do we write "Where does he play for?" or "Who does he play for?"

Tags: questions

> Mohamed Salah plays for Liverpool.

If I want to ask a question, is it correct to say:

> Where does he play for?

Or

> Who does he play for?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the team you ask

> Who does Mo Salah play for?

if you ask

> Where does Mo Salah play?

you may get the answer "Striker" or similar although I suppose they could answer "Anfield" as that is Liverpool FC home ground.